# Why does manual search with "for" result better than using GridsearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, gridsearchcv

I read several places to use the GridsearchCV algorithm to find the best hyperparameters, but when in the knn algorithm, I set the number of neighbors to three and use train_test_spilt, it shows a difference of 7057, and when I use GridsearchCV to find the best neighbor, the number is 4. when I use 4, show the difference is 11473
How to increase the difference with the best numbers of neighbor?
code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

file_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Ashil-Rayan\Desktop\Data\RankHome\housePricelimit2.csv", header=None)
data = file_data.drop(6, axis=1)
target = file_data[6]

z = []
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

#find best neighbor with for

for i in range(1,10):
    knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=i,  weights="distance",)
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predicts = knn.predict(X_test)
    result = mean_squared_error(y_test, predicts)
    result = sqrt(result)
    score = knn.score(X_test, y_test)
    z.append((i, result, score))
x = []
y = []
for i in z:
    x.append(i[0])
    y.append(i[1])
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlabel("n_neighbors")
plt.ylabel("mean_squared_error")
plt.show()
print(z[1])
print(z[3])
#use GridsearchCV

parametrs = {"n_neighbors" : range(1, 50),
             "weights" : ["uniform", "distance"]}
Grid = GridSearchCV(KNeighborsRegressor(), parametrs)
Grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(Grid.best_params_)
# print(knn.predict([new_data]))
print(knn.score(X_test, y_test))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8txez.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWdI6.png)

Comment: `it shows a difference of 7057` What is difference? Is difference good or bad?

Comment: good, The average of the numbers is 100,000

Answer (score 0):

Your "for" code is only doing the "GridSearch" part of `GridSearchCV`; it does not do the "CV" part.

During "CV", the argument dataset is split into several train/eval subsets. Since such train-subsets are smaller than the original train dataset, then the model has less generalization power, etc.

Should be especially clear with KNN, where the total number of embedded reference samples matters a lot. See for yourself, print out the `KNeighborsRegressor.n_samples_fit_` attribute value for your "for" code vs. the "GridSearchCV" code. Yours will be significantly higher.